# Change Dimension Storage Type as Real-time rolap but error occurs

Tags: ssas

I Create a measure group and two dimensions using  [AdventureWorksDW2012], I try to change one dimension's storage mode with setting proactive caching as Real-Time ROlap. There is no any warning message when deploying and processing, but error occurs when I query in sql server analysis services, see below for the error messages and the screen capture.

Error occurred retrieving child nodes: the current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

Does somebody have a hit ?

Regards

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us your code?

Comment: There's probably another error message.   Can you post all of them?

Comment: Since I do not know how to paste an image, I show the DimProduct code:   the Procative Caching property   
<ProactiveCaching dwd:design-time-name="ccc503c5-b973-40ae-bab1-23c2574e57fa">
.....
      <NotificationTechnique>Server</NotificationTechnique>
      <TableNotifications>
        <TableNotification>
          <DbTableName>DimProduct</DbTableName>
          <DbSchemaName>dbo</DbSchemaName>
        </TableNotification>
      </TableNotifications>
    </Source>
  </ProactiveCaching>

Comment: the StorageMode  property is :
  <StorageMode>Rolap</StorageMode>
  <CurrentStorageMode>Molap</CurrentStorageMode>